# What does the percent sign mean in Yaml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml

I noticed that in the i18n rails guide, they have the following code:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      template:
        header:
          one:   "1 error prohibited this %{model} from being saved"
          other: "%{count} errors prohibited this %{model} from being saved"
        body:    "There were problems with the following fields:"
```

What do the `%{...}` mean? How is this different from `#{...}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read the guide a little more, you'll come across the [Passing variables to translations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations) section:

> You can use variables in the translation messages and pass their values from the view.
>
> ```
> # app/views/home/index.html.erb
> <%=t 'greet_username', :user => "Bill", :message => "Goodbye" %>
>
> # config/locales/en.yml
> en:
>   greet_username: "%{message}, %{user}!"
> ```

and the [Interpolation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#interpolation) section:

> In many cases you want to abstract your translations so that variables can be interpolated into the translation. For this reason the I18n API provides an interpolation feature.
>
> All options besides `:default` and `:scope` that are passed to `#translate` will be interpolated to the translation:
>
> ```
> I18n.backend.store_translations :en, :thanks => 'Thanks %{name}!'
> I18n.translate :thanks, :name => 'Jeremy'
> # => 'Thanks Jeremy!'
> ```

So the `%{...}` stuff doesn't have anything to do with YAML, that's I18n's way of handling variable interpolation in the messages.

Comment: more importantly... this is just string interpolation. `'foo_%{h}' % {h: 'bar'}` returns `'foo_bar'`

Comment: @Mallanaga But the question is about `%{...}` vs `#{...}`. The latter is Ruby string interpolation, the former is run-time "interpolation" (which would better be called "substitution" IMO) via `sprintf`'s `String#%` alias.